# How do I load a file in Javascript, similar to file api, but from a web directory?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to javascript so I have what is probably an easy question.

I currently am loading files using `<input type="file" id="file"/>`. In javascript I can then use that file for what I need.

Is there a way to do this for a file already on the web server? Instead of the user finding a local file on their machine, a file will load from a directory on the server instead.

I guess what I need is a method to turn the file on my server into a 'file' of the same type that I get when I use the input form.

Edit: I am loading an epub book. Instead of selecting the file from my computer, I want to have a list of files already on the server that I can load by clicking.

Comment: I think we need a bit more information.  You mention that you want "a method to turn the file on my server into a 'file' of the same type that I get when I use the input form."  But what sort of 'file' is that.  How do you process the file normally?

Comment: Javascript is client side language not server side. You can find file on web server using a server side language like PHP, ASP.NET, etc

Comment: Essentially you'll need to use a server side language as @Aboodred1 said. You could use AJAX to pull the file for use into javascript.

Comment: Have you ever used [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)? Javascript can definitely be used on the server side.